# Example Applications of Some Data Structures

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

I have knownledge of following data structures and I'm looking for example usage of them in real-world applicatons;

- Binary Search Trees
- Red-Black Trees
- Interval Trees(Augmented RBT)
- Hash Tables

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you expect people to post links to applications? Source code examples? Or just name some applications where such a structure might be used?

Comment: I dont want code examples. Just name of applications. For example; we can use an augmented red-black tree to find i'th element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Binary Search Trees**

BST is used very widely for information organizing, indexing and retrieving. **Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer of Microsoft** are the most well-known app which uses BST.

**2. Red-Black Trees** (we'd like to call it "AVL trees")

 RBT is just a specific kind of BST. With an RBT, we can quickly locate data structures corresponding to a specific value. **Linux Kernel** links together all the memory area objects in a RBT while managing vm_area_struct.

**3. Augmented RBT**

Augmented RBT works very much like a normal RBT, with the exception that it keeps additional information in each node. **Linux Kernel** introduced Augmented RBT to improve the function of the page attribute table (PAT) support for the x86 architecture.

**4. Hash Table**

Hash is used extremely widely. For example the famous **MD5 hash algorithm**, **P2P transport** etc.